# Django Form submit manipulate values

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

so currently I am stuck with a Message app in Django.

So I am passing a list of user names to my template to a input field for autocomplete suggestions who to send the message to.

Now when I save the model it says "receiver must be a user instance".

How can I change/manipulate the value and look the associated user with username up in my database (like I tried in my clean & save function, but I think the error message appears before it comes to the lines)

Thanks very much!

EDIT the code:

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    receiver = forms.CharField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        receiver_list = kwargs.pop('receiver_list', None)
        users_list = kwargs.pop('users_list', None)
        super(MessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['receiver'].widget = ListTextWidget(name='receiver_list', users_list=users_list)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MessageForm, self).clean()
        receiver = User.objects.get(username =cleaned_data.get("receiver"))

    def save(self, commit=True):

        message = super(MessageForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # clean data
        message.receiver = User.objects.get(username =self.cleaned_data['receiver'])
        message.subject = self.cleaned_data['subject']
        message.text = self.cleaned_data['text']

        if commit:
            message.save()
        return message

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = {'receiver', 'subject', 'text'}
        labels = {'receiver': 'receiver', 'subject': 'subject', 'text': 'text'}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, })}
```

Comment: Don’t paste images, insert your code in your question.

Comment: Also paste the trace back, it’s not clear where the error is caused.

Comment: added traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a local variable `receiver` in your `clean` method, but you don't do anything with it. You need to assign that back to the cleaned data.

```
cleaned_data['receiver'] = receiver
```

Comment: Just did it but returns this error: This QueryDict instance is immutable

Comment: That's not coming from this code; `cleaned_data` is not a QueryDict. Update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: See question, I have added the traceback. Thanks in advance Daniel!

Comment: Well, you appear to have set `self.data`, not `cleaned_data`.